# Looking for suitable workflow tool

Tags: workflow, business-process-management

Our specific requirements are

1. We are looking for a workflow tool which supports on premise deployment.
2. The workflow can be easily designed by drag and drop option.
3. Should have the option to configure the rules and approval matrix by UI.
4. Implementing/Utilizing our existing user/roles authorisation which exists in our DB.
5. Integrate within our application portal to trigger the workflow and process the workflow    (approving the request ,etc. within out portal)
6. Visualizing the workflow in our portal.

We are open to use open-source / enterprise versions.
Kindly share your experiences. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/32063/bpm-workflow-software-for-personal-use

Answer (score 0):

"Easily designed by drag and drop" works only for domain specific use cases.  You cannot really find an existing solution with an easy workflow authoring experience for non technical users unless it is part of a very specific application.

So if you want something that non technical users can use you have to develop your own UI and DSL for the workflow definition taking your domain expertise into account. If you are up to this task then you can use an existing *workflow as code* workflow solution like [temporal.io](https://www.temporal.io/) to implement your DSL logic in a scalable and reliable way.